# Replacing a C function from a common .o file for the scope of a single test executable

Tags: c, unit-testing, linker

So, I've got a library call `init_foo()`, and a function `bar()` that calls it. These live in `library.o` along with some other useful stuff that both need.

I want to write some code, `bar_init_failure.t.c`, to test what happens when `init_foo()` fails, without actually setting up the failure. In Perl, the bulk of our codebase, I'd launch [Test::Resub](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Test-Resub/lib/Test/Resub.pm) and replace the library call with a stub that returns a failure code. To accomplish something similar in C, I was vaguely under the impression that I could redefine `init_foo` in the source for `bar_init_failure.t.c` and still link against `library.o` for the rest of the code, but `gcc` and `ld` complain about the duplicate symbols (instead of picking the first one) so I think I must be wrong about something (and I'm pretty rusty on this sort of stuff, so I'm not over-confident in my strategy).

Is there some way to appease the linker here, or is there another strategy that I should be using? (I'd prefer not to have to hack up the `library.c` code if I can help it.)

Comment: What linker?  You might have a symbol aliasing or interposing feature you can use.  The GNU toolchain certainly does.

Comment: Standard `ld`, `gcc` toolchain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can recompile library.c into a shared library, then you can redefine `init_foo()` within the unit tests. ld won't complain about duplicate symbols, neither at compile time, nor at execution`, and will invoke the function in the executable whatever the dynamic library contain - at least on Unix-like systems - I never tried on Windows.

This may prevent you from testing `bar()` as you won't be able to call the real `init_foo()` in the other tests ; unless you use [dlsym()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlsym) to invoke it from your own `init_foo()`, for instance when a global variable is set.